# PHPList Cron does not run, rather the cron file is opened

Tags: cron-task, phplist

I have installed in a vps:
Versión PHP 7.2.2
PhpList 3.4.5
Plesk Onyx
Version 17.8.11 Update #66

I always execute the cron tasks as administrator. In previous versions it works very well.
But in this version I have the problem that the cron does not execute, rather it opens the file.

The server does well with other cron. Only with this version of phplist does not work, rather open the phplist file.
How to correct it?

```html
Run scheduled task
Task "/usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/admin/index.php -p processqueue -c /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/config/config.php" completed with error in 0 seconds, output:

phpList - phpList version 3.4.5 (c) 2000-2019 phpList Ltd, https://www.phplist.com
<title>phpList :: phpList :: Enviar la cola</title></head>
<body class="invisible processqueue">
<div id="dialog"></div><div id="hiddendiv"></div>

<div class="container-fluid">

<div id="container">

<nav id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top col-lg-2 col-md-3">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse_" data-target="#menuTop" aria-expanded="false">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a href="./" class="navbar-brand"><img src="ui/phplist-ui-bootlist/logo.svg" alt="phpList, email newsletter manager, logo" title="phpList, the world's most popular Open Source newsletter manager" /></a>
</nav>
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar col-lg-2 col-md-3">
<div id="context-menu" class="menu block">
</div>
<div id="recent" class="menu visited block">
</div> 
<div class="col-sm-12 sidebar-footer">
<div id="language">

<div id="languageswitcher">
<form name="languageswitchform" method="post" action="">
<select name="setlanguage" onchange="document.languageswitchform.submit()">
<option value="ar" >العربية</option>
<option value="bg" >Bulgarian</option>
<option value="ca" >Català</option>
<option value="cs" >Česky</option>
<option value="da" >danske</option>
<option value="de" >Deutsch</option>
<option value="el" >ελληνικά</option>
<option value="en" >english</option>
<option value="es" selected="selected">español</option>
<option value="es_AR" >Español (Argentina)</option>
<option value="fa" >فارسی</option>
<option value="fi" >suomi</option>
<option value="fr" >française</option>
<option value="gl" >Galician</option>
<option value="he" >עברית</option>
<option value="hr" >Croatian</option>
<option value="hu" >magyar</option>
<option value="is" >Icelandic</option>
<option value="it" >italiano</option>
<option value="ja" >日本語</option>
<option value="lt" >Lithuanian</option>
<option value="lv" >Latvian</option>
<option value="nb" >Norwegian</option>
<option value="nl" >Nederlands</option>
<option value="nl_BE" >Vlaams</option>
<option value="pl" >polski</option>
<option value="pt" >Portuguese</option>
<option value="pt_BR" >Portuguès (Brazil)</option>
<option value="ro" >Romanian</option>
<option value="ru" >русский</option>
<option value="sk" >Slovak</option>
<option value="sl" >Slovenian</option>
<option value="sq" >Albanian</option>
<option value="sr" >Srpski</option>
<option value="sv" >svenska</option>
<option value="tr" >Turkish</option>
<option value="vi" >Việt</option>
<option value="zh_CN" >简体中文</option>
<option value="zh_TW" >Traditional Chinese</option>
</select>
</form>
</div> </div>

<div id="logged">
<a id="login" class="navbar-btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="./?page=home">conectarse</a> </div>
</div>
</div> <!-- end #sidebar -->

<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-3" id="content" tabindex=-1>
<div id="globalhelp">
</div>
<div id="wrapp">
<div id="progressbar"></div>
<!-- content starts here -->
<h4 class="pagetitle">Enviar la cola</h4><div class="hidden"><a href="./?page=home&amp;tk=a503fa16f7b08a7d01be978eeb472297" title="Ir a la página principal">Página principal</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

3 months later i think you already found the answer, but anyway since I just found the answer.

I run phplist in plesk.

The problem was the php was using. In plesk when you use php from command line gets the oldest php. I replaced the php with /opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php and worked just fine.

If you also run plesk, try this article: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003766853-How-to-specify-command-line-command-php-version-for-SSH-user-on-the-Plesk-server-

my phplist scripts looks like this now:

## !/bin/bash

/opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/my-domain.com/news/admin/index.php -c /var/www/vhosts/my-domain.com/news/config/config.php $*

run with ./phplist -pprocessqueue (from command line)

alex